# How to parse my JSON data in IOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios5, ios5.1

Can anyone tell me how to parse my json data in IOS5. I'm providing my JSON data below:

```
{
 "fieldType" : "Alphanumeric",
 "fieldName" : "Name"
},{
 "fieldType" : "Numeric",
 "fieldName" : "Card Num"
},{
 "fieldType" : "Alphanumeric",
 "fieldName" : "Pin Num"
}
```

Also is this JSON format correct or do I need to change the JSON format? When I try to parse JSON using below code I get an error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)

The code I'm using:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [filedList dataUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
if (jsonData) 
{
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        // Handle Error and return
        return;

    }
    NSArray *keys = [jsonObjects allKeys];

    // values in foreach loop
    for (NSString *key in keys)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [jsonObjects objectForKey:key]);
    }                
} 
else 
{
    // Handle Error 
}
```

Comment: use http://jsonlint.com to validate your JSON. It's invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any type of parsing, first of all `NSLog` the JSON or XML string then start writing your parsing your code.

In your case as per the JSON string you mentioned its a array of dictionaries, and once you got your jsonObjects do this to get your data..

```
 id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonObjects);
// as per your example its an array of dictionaries so

NSArray* array = (NSArray*) jsonObjects;
for(NSDictionary* dict in array)
{
NSString* obj1 = [dict objectForKey:@"fieldType"];
NSString* obj2 = [dict objectForKey:@"fieldName"];

enter code here
enter code here
}
```

In this way you can parse the your json string.. for more details go through this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) by Raywenderlich.

Answer (score 3):

The JSON data is not correctly formatted. Since you have an array of items, you need to enclose this in `[ ... ]`:

```
[
    {
     "fieldType" : "Alphanumeric",
     "fieldName" : "Name"
    },{
     "fieldType" : "Numeric",
     "fieldName" : "Card Num"
    },{
     "fieldType" : "Alphanumeric",
     "fieldName" : "Pin Num"
    }
]
```

Now `JSONObjectWithData` gives you an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary` objects (because of the NSJSONReadingMutableContainers flag).

You can walk through the parsed data with

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in jsonObjects) {
    for (NSString *key in dict) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
    }
}
```